# Grid | Optimizations

Tags: html, css

I have built this grid, but there are a few issues with it. If you were to run this code, the text color is white, but If I put this code into my website, the text is coming out black for some reason. Also, Box 1, 5, and 9, are not maintaining the same size as the other squares within the grid. As you can probably imagine, this is creating other optimization issues as well when the grid is changing based on said media query. Is anyone able to help to figure out what is causing this issue?

Bonus Help: I want box 1, 5, 9 to be centered in its designated squared. 1 and 9 would be left aligned, but still centered.

You can view how this is looking on my website here: [Grid on actual website](https://www.seductivebox.com/test-page)

```html
</h1><!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title></title>
  <style media="screen">
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 1em;
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
  text-align: left;
  color: white;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: Open Sans, sans-serif;
}

/* .grid>div {
  background: #2b5eaf;
  padding: 1em;
} */

/* .grid>div:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #2b5eaf;
} */

.box-1, .box-5, .box-9 {
  background: #2b5eaf;
  color: white;
}

.button {
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px 50px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 12px;
}

.group1 {
  padding: 48px;
  justify-content: center;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 30px;
}

p {
  font-size: 14px;
}

.box-5 {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}


.button2 {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  border: 2px solid #008CBA;
}

.button2:hover {
  background-color: #008CBA;
  color: white;
}

.photo > img {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.photo {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}


/* TABLET VIEW */
  @media only screen and (min-width: 759px) and (max-width: 1279px) {
.grid {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  text-align: left;
  grid-gap: 0;
}

.grid>div {
    height: 100%;
}

.box-2,.box-6, .box-7 {
    display: none;
}
.box-8 {
    grid-column: 2;
    grid-row: 3;
}

.box-9 {
    grid-column: 1;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 24px;
}
  }


/* MOBILE VIEW */
  @media only screen and (max-width: 759px) {
.grid {
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  text-align: left;
  grid-gap: 0;
}

.box-1 {
    grid-row: 3;
    grid-column: 1/3;
}
.box-2 {
    grid-row: 2;
    grid-column: 1;
}
.box-3 {
    grid-row: 2;
    grid-column: 2;
}
.box-5 {
    grid-row: 1;
    grid-column: 1/3;
}

.box-7, .box-8, .box-9 {
    display: none;
}
  }

  </style>


</head>

<body>
  <div class="grid">
<!-- CLASS NUMBER READ LEFT TO RIGHT FROM DESKTOP VIEW -->
<div class="box-1">
  <div class="group1">
  <h1 class="quote">"Lingerie is not about seducing men;
    It's about embracing womanhood"</h1><br><br> <p>- Dita Von Teese</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="box-2">
  <img class="photo" src="https://i.imgur.com/p5IOrlS.png" alt="">
</div>

<div class="box-3">
  <img class="photo" src="https://i.imgur.com/JKKqZjj.png" alt="">
</div>

<div class="box-4">
  <img class="photo" src="https://i.imgur.com/pI3g39l.png" alt="">
</div>

<div class="box-5">
  <h1>Discover Something Sexy In You</h1>
  <a class="button button2" href="https://www.subbly.co/checkout/buy/112646">Take Style Quiz</a>
</div>

<div class="box-6">
  <img class="photo" src="https://i.imgur.com/2mVzhR6.png" alt="">
</div>

<div class="box-7">
  <img class="photo" src="https://i.imgur.com/bIcsE4S.png" alt="">
</div>

<div class="box-8">
  <img class="photo" src="https://i.imgur.com/LnUV9eF.png" alt="">
</div>

<div class="box-9">
  <div class="group1">
  <h1>"My wife and I absolute LOVE our SeductiveBox subscription! This bring more excitement to our love life. Plus this is the
    only subscription that gets unwrapped TWICE!"</h1><br><br> <p>- Wendy S.</p>
    </div>
</div>

  </div>



</body>

</html>
```

Comment: 'the text is coming out black for some reason' - please do some searching youself. In this case one thing to do is to use your browser's dev tools inspect facility to see who/what/where is setting the color to black.

Comment: Well I found where it says, what im assuming is a root directory ( :root{} ), and the "primary-color" is different than white. This color code, i have no idea what to do with this information because that color code isnt inserted into my code at all. (color code #353535)

Comment: Sorry I meant you to look at the element you are interested in and look at all the CSS being set for it and to see whether yours is being picked up. And then look at the computed styles for that element and scroll down to see what color is set at.

Comment: Finally got it working. I added style="color:#ffffff"; into my h1 and it overrode that black color code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

style="color:#ffffff";

Above is the code I inserted into my h1 to override the random black color text I had. Code appears as so:

```html
<div class="box-1">
  <div class="group1">
  <h1 class="quote" style="color:#ffffff";>"Lingerie is not about seducing men;
    It's about embracing womanhood"</h1><br><br> <p>- Dita Von Teese</p>
    </div>
</div>
```